# How to consume Json from rest template and map for each element to another Json in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am not able to map a consumed json to another json to each element by using REST template in Spring Boot

Controller code:

```
public List<Getrequests> getallrequests() {
List<Getrequests> list=Serviceobj.allrequestdata(); 
return list;
}
```

Service code:

```
public List<Getrequests> allrequestdata() {
String urlGETList = "http://localhost:8082/myapp/userinfo/getusertype/asd454";//get by id call
ResponseEntity<Usertype[]> responseEntity =resttemplateobj.getForEntity(urlGETList, Usertype[].class);
Usertype[]objects = responseEntity.getBody();
List results = admininfoDaoobj.getallrequestsdata();
//results.add(objects);if i un comment this line of code i am getting 1 output means it just add to the list only
return results;
}
```

Dao code:

```
public List<Getrequests> getallrequestsdata(){
String hql = "FROM Createrequest";
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
Query<Createrequest> query = getSession().createQuery(hql,Createrequest.class);
List resultlist= query.getResultList();
return resultlist;
}
```

Getrequests pojo class:

```
public class Getrequests{
        private String userid;
        private String username;
        private String userphoneno;

     .......getters and setters.....
}
```

User type pojo class:

```
public class Usertype{
private String usertype;
private String useraddress;

 .......getters and setters.....
}
```

1 output:

```
[
  {
    "userid":"asd454",
    "username":"satya",
    "userphoneno":"1234567890"
   },
  {
    "userid":"asd455",
    "username":"satya",
    "userphoneno":"1234567890"
   }
    [
    {
     "usertype":"admin,agent",
     "useraddress:"dsadasd,asdasdsa"
     },
     {
     "usertype":"agent",
     "useraddress:"asdasdsa"
     },
    ]
]
```

2 output

If I comment `resultlist.add(objects)` in Service code means it's not added to the getrequest list then I am getting below output:

```
[
  {
    "userid":"asd454",
    "username":"satya",
    "userphoneno":"1234567890"
   },
  {
    "userid":"asd455",
    "username":"satya",
    "userphoneno":"1234567890"
   }
]
```

But I need to map for each userid, I need to display the usertype and user address like below output.

3 Output

```
[
  {
    "userid":"asd454",
          [
            {
             "usertype":"admin,agent",
             "useraddress:"dsadasd,asdasdsa"
             }  ]  
    "username":"satya",
    "userphoneno":"1234567890"
   },
  {
    "userid":"asd455",
        [
           {
            "usertype":"agent",
            "useraddress:"asdasdsa"
            }
        ]
    "username":"satya",
    "userphoneno":"1234567890"
   }
]
```

I also tried the rest template call in Dao then also not getting.

How can I map for each userid to display the usertype and user address like as above shown 3 output.

Comment: ???? u want to hold references in `Getrequests` like a `List<Usertype>` maybe?????

Comment: @ AntJavaDev please explain little bit in depth

Comment: apologies, please find an answer below

Answer (score 0):

From your snippets, it looks like you want to generate a specific POJO signature.
There are plenty of tools which can give you a stub out of a sample json request.

From your example, i would guess that changing the `Getrequests` would do the trick,
like :

```
public class Getrequests{
        private String userid;
        private String username;
        private String userphoneno;
        private Usertype userType;

     .......getters and setters.....
}
```

You might need to change it to a list reference as well, depending on your schema and your overall requirement.

EDIT

```
public class Getrequests{
    private String userid;
    private String username;
    private String userphoneno;
    private List<Usertype> userType;
}
```

If i make the reference a list, then the below samples are the output :

Single object:

```
{
   "userid":"69",
   "username":"asd",
   "userphoneno":"09876",
   "userType":[
      {
         "usertype":"01",
         "useraddress":"1234"
      }
   ]
}
```

As An array :

```
[
   {
      "userid":"94",
      "username":"asd",
      "userphoneno":"09876",
      "userType":[
         {
            "usertype":"01",
            "useraddress":"1234"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "userid":"53",
      "username":"asd",
      "userphoneno":"09876",
      "userType":[
         {
            "usertype":"01",
            "useraddress":"1234"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: i also changed my code at "private Usertype usertype" to private List<USertype> usertype in getrequests.then also not getting actual output i mean i got the 1st output what i showned above.

Comment: hmm from the first place the sample output is not a valid json, thus i am not quite sure what u r trying to achieve. Would you mind posting the actual response?

Comment: Also the `Createrequest` is really a table ? could you post that schema as well?

Comment: yes `createrequest` is my another model class which was operate on db.

Comment: 3 out put is my expected output if it was wrong then please comment me what u r output in u r point of view and how to achieve

Comment: please find the samples in the edited question, i would guess that the confusion goes on with the list reference

Comment: ok if i add like u  r way in `getrequests` and how to map for each resttemplate`usertype` request to put in my `getrequest` i mean what i have do  updates on my service code as above questioned code snippet.

Comment: change `ResponseEntity<Getrequests[]> responseEntity =resttemplateobj.getForEntity(urlGETList, Getrequests[].class);`

Comment: i tried now but i did not get as u expected i am getting 1 output which was in question:i mean the user type data not shown on the getrequests list

Comment: then the problem relies somewhere else, please try to clear out your use-case, try to clear out your logic and please correct the wrong jsons and wrong code snippets. It seems that the confusion indeed relies in your service method, would you maybe elaborate a bit more on what your are trying to achieve. From the first place your snippet does not even compile

Comment: please let me know how to share my screen to you then i will explain clearly.if any possible